# Unable to save salary input field to model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a registration form that allows a user to enter their salary and save it within my model. I am using [Django-money](https://github.com/django-money/django-money) in order to store the salary field. However, after submitting the form, I am getting this error:

```
Object of type Money is not JSON serializable
```

**This is my code:**

**models.py:**

```
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField 

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name = 'register')
    salary = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
```

**views.py:**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("login") #place login here
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'myapp/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py:**

```
class ProfileRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['salary']
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class PrSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    salary = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, read_only = True)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('salary')
```

I'll be using an API later but I always get the error shown above. How can I avoid the error and save the salary data to my model?

Comment: Seems that you might need to implement or at least extend the default serializer to handle `MoneyField` objects. See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/django-money/django-money/issues/291) for further info.

Comment: Could you show the view dealing with the submitted form? And also the form actually?

Comment: Please view my question again, I have updated it.

Comment: @albert I have extended the default serializer but I'm not able to save the data into my model.